# Can AccessibilityService click button without opening the app (invisible mode)

Tags: kotlin, accessibility

I need to perform click event on background without opening app (third party app). using accessibility service, we can perform click event while app screen in foreground but for background the node for button on that screen is not found

or any other way to achieve this?